# How to merge rows of a large Pandas dataframe after concatenation?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I need to do a `pivot_table` operation on a very large dataframe. However, due to memory issues, I need to do it chunk by chunk, then `pd_concat(list_of_df, axis=0)`. Next, I fill the `NaN` values with 0. However, there are duplicated indices and I will need to perform a `groupby` operation. Before `groupby`, the dataframe is:

```
Sample    Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    Col_D
  1         0        1        0        1
  1         1        0        0        0
  2         1        0        1        0
  2         0        1        0        0
```

where `Sample` is the index. I would like to get this after `groupby` operation:

```
Sample    Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    Col_D
  1         1        1        0        1
  2         1        1        1        0
```

I did `groupby(df.index)` and tried using `first(), last(), sum()` etc. I can't seem to produce the correct dataframe as I have the original full pivoted dataframe for checking, where I check it using `df_chunk.equals(df_original)`.

Comment: Please post us a reproducible example here using seeded-random data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.any()` within a groupby:

```
>>> df.groupby('Sample').any().astype(int).reset_index()

   Sample  Col_A  Col_B  Col_C  Col_D
0       1      1      1      0      1
1       2      1      1      1      0
```

Side note--`any()` usually has an `axis` argument (as a method of a DataFrame itself, not groupby object), but as a groupby method it seems that it does not.  It looks like the default is `axis=0`, though.